# How to check the value value of the background url by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a box that has a css `background-image`. By jQuery I want to check the value of this background-image, and if it contain a specific name then `console.log("done")`.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
var bgName = $(".leftBox").css("background-image");
  if (bgName.search("Z3Escd") == 0){
  console.log("done");
}
// Z3Escd is the name of my file that it must check.
```

Unfortunately it does not work. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/danials/qU8W7/

Any idea to find some certain characters in the string?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to check? Should the condition be fulfilled if the string is found or not found? Please provide a complete description of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by name of background image? Url?

Comment: how can anyone here evaluate `doesn't work` when you haven't explained expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var bgName = $(".leftBox").css("background-image");
if (bgName.search("Z3Escd") != -1){
  console.log("done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if bgName.search result is >= 0. That's because String.search returns index of start of searched substring, and -1 if substring was not found.

Answer (score -1):

You use your search function wrong.
The result of bgName.search is the startindex of your provided string in the to search string.
The best method would be to check if the string endswith:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

var bgName = $(".leftBox").css("background-image");
  if (bgName.endsWith ("Z3Escd")){
  console.log("done");
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the OP want's to test whether the value ends with that string?